# HP raid illegal opcode

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, update, debian-buster

i did an apt-get dist-upgrade on my HP Gen8 Microserver, it does not boot afterwards. (it must have updated to Debian 10 Buster, i am using the stable channel.)

The onboard-raid says. disk configured, but not present. obviously it cannot boot, if it does not find the disk :(

If i try to go to the RAID-Setup, it gives me what they call a Red Screen of Death, basicaly an error "illegal opcode" and a register dump.

The HDD is in the optical-Drive-Bay and configured in the RAID-tool as a single disk to make it selectable as a boot drive.

What did cause that?
Does the raid controller write something to the disk that might have been overwritten by the update?
May the Update have change some form of ID of the disk?
What's wrong with the RAID-Setup-Thing?
Hints for fixing the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm very familiar of the Red Screen of Death :) Could you tell me more details about that? If you're getting a Red Screen of Death, that means the CPU threw out an NMI and the exception type. There should be some information that is dumped into iLO's IML (integrated management log). What does that tell you?

Comment: @kingDuken Sorry for not getting back top you. Busy week.
I had the server up and running again by connecting the HDD to a USB-SATA-Adapter and booting off the internal USB-port. 
At the moment I am unable to reproduce the red screen of death :( 
when it says: 
'press F5 to run the HP Storage Administrator (ACU / HPSA)' press f5 and get 
'ACU will start automatically'
**this is the point where i got the red screen**
now it just goes to the "Non-system Disk or disk error"-Output :/
so the raid admin doesn't even crash anymore, it plainly ignores me.